# RequestTimedOutIOException

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-jms

I have ActiveMQ broker (5.6.0), and spring-JMS producer. I am using JMS queues, and not topics. It works great, but when the JMS-producer have many messages to sent, I sometimes get:

```
'org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized
exception occured during JMS processing; nested exception is
javax.jms.JMSException:
org.apache.activemq.transport.RequestTimedOutIOException'
```

although all the messages are actually being sent to the broker.

Comment: Can you post your producer code ?

Comment: what is your send timeout ? is your subscriber online or offline durable ?

Comment: I did not configured timeout. I use spring to define jms-listener as a producer (in spring-context.xml), and spring JMSTemplate (inside producer) to send messages to queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending a lot of messages using JMSTemplate configured with a plain connection factory out a Java EE container is never a good idea. It fires up a lot of network connections, build new sessions etc, for every message.

Read [JMSTemplate Gotchas](http://activemq.apache.org/jmstemplate-gotchas.html) from ActiveMQ for some background and help to solve the issues.

Just configuring a PooledConnectionFactory och a CachingConnectionFactory might solve you issues.

That said, I don't know if it will solve your `RequestTimedOutIOException`, but it's a good place to start.

Comment: Thanx. I am using 'CachingConnectionFactory'. I changed to 'PooledConnectionFactory' and still the exception occurs (but the message is actually being sent). The wired thing is that this exception has no effect, meaning: All the messages are **always** being sent to broker successfuly, even when some raised 'RequestTimedOutIOException' at JMS client side.

Comment: It's probably some retry mechanism somewhere under the hood making it work anyway. It's a bad sign to get exception anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. In my case I had only to increase sendTimeout param value of the connectionFactory from 2000 to 5000 or higher.